# Possible meaning of キズ(kizu)

Tags: translation, meaning, manga

Panel from manga おじょじょじょ by クール教信者

[image: 超金持ちの令嬢 地獄巡 春 高飛車なのが主にキズ]

The text says:

> 超金持ちの令嬢 地獄巡 春
>   高飛車なのが主にキズ

What does `キズ` mean here? It does not seem to be 傷 (wound/injury), and since it’s katakana I suspect it’s some kind of slang but I did not find anything on zokugo-dict...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, キズ is part of a set phrase which is 玉にキズ or 玉に傷 (lit. A scratch on the jewel) which is analogous to the English version *A fly in the ointment.*

The phrase then means that it's a small annoying something that sours the mood of enjoyment or success (similar to how a scratched jewel isn't as beautiful as an undamaged one, and is as such a minor annoyance or flaw).

This might be describing the characteristic of the character with the rest of the phrase at the beginning:

> 高飛車なのが、玉にキズ
>   (Her being) domineering is the "scratch on the jewel (lit.)"

A very loose translation that is probably truer to an English tone is:

> She thinks she's on top and that's her (only) flaw.

Special thanks to Chocolate and By137 for the point-outs.

Comment: 玉 means jewel in that phrase. And it's not saying she is a fly in the ointment, but the domineering part of her character is her only flaw.

Comment: `Domineering, but` `She thinks she's on top but` --　「高飛車なの**が**玉にキズ」の「が」は、 but じゃなくて、主格の格助詞・・

Comment: @Chocolate なるほどね。では、答えを直します。いつもどおりありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

玉(たま)に瑕(きず) is a proverb.

それさえなければ完全であるのに、ほんの少しの欠点があること。
[https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/138638/meaning/m0u/玉に瑕/](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/138638/meaning/m0u/%E7%8E%89%E3%81%AB%E7%91%95/)

玉 refers to a precious stone.
瑕 is a flaw, an imperfection.

A precious stone which would otherwise be very valuable and expensive, loses most of its value due to a small imperfection.

According to the site below it comes from an ancient Chinese proverb.
[http://yain.jp/i/玉に瑕](http://yain.jp/i/%E7%8E%89%E3%81%AB%E7%91%95)